# Segmentation of a solid 3-D voxel cube

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, image-segmentation, voxel

I am trying to perform watershed segmentation on a 30x30x30 (a binvox converted to `npy`) cube. It can have two features such as a rectangular passage & circular passage. I want to segment the cube into two different cubes with each feature.

The numpy array i get finally is binary, `1` where there is solid and `0` where it is hollow.

I tried using the same approach which we use for images (connected component labelling followed by watershed segmentation) using `scikit-image` library. It fails for the basic file with two features. I also tried [Connected Components 3D](https://github.com/seung-lab/connected-components-3d) followed by `scikit-image` watershed but nothing fruitful is coming by way.

Please see code below.

```py
inf = np.load(path/to/npy)

D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(inf)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, labels=inf, indices=False, min_distance=1)

# ccl
markers = ndimage.label(localMax)
# perform a connected component analysis on the local peaks, using 8-connectivity, then appy the Watershed algorithm

labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=inf)

# loop over the unique labels returned by the Watershed algorithm

for label in np.unique(labels):
     if label == 0:
         continue
     mask = np.ones(inf.shape, dtype=np.int32)
     mask[labels == label] = 0
     np.save(path/to/save)
```

Since I am working on this alone I might need to change my thought process. So, if anyone can guide me where I am wrong that would be really helpful.